# Showing a function is limited

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity

This is something about which I'm quite confident, but I would really like to be sure

Let $f(x)$ be a continuos function in $\mathbb{R}$

Then if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pm\infty} f(x) = l \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)$ is bounded. (There exists $a, b$ such that $a \le f(x) \le b \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$)

I think I can come up with a formal proof, but a more naive one would be to say that in any finite intervals there exist such $a, b$ (it's just the weirstrass theorem).
If trouble happens, it has to be in a neighborood of infinity.
So if the limit is finite, this means that also there the function is bounded above (not necessarily by $l$) so it's proven

Any feedback appreciated

**Formal Proof**

Let's focus on the limit to $+\infty$.

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pm\infty} f(x) = l \Rightarrow$

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists N : \forall x \ge N : |f(x) - l| < \varepsilon$$

This means that $\forall \varepsilon$, calling $\displaystyle M_{\epsilon} = \max_{x \in (0, N)} f$    we can say that $f(x) \le \max(M_{\epsilon}, l + \epsilon)$

Since $M_\epsilon$ is always finite, and so is $l + \epsilon$, we have a proof.

Comment: If you make the argument precise, you have a proof. The idea is indeed that. We have $f$ bounded on a neighbourhood of each of $\pm\infty$, what remains of $\mathbb{R}$ is contained in some $[a,b]$, on that $f$ is bounded too.

Comment: @DanielFischer I wrote an attempt to a formal proof. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is unusual, it shows an entire family of bounds. You only consider $x > 0$, and you only produce upper bounds on $f(x)$, no lower bounds. You know how to address these points, however, and provide lower bounds for the values of $f$, and bounds for the values at negative $x$, I suppose.

There's a technical detail wrong, you wrote

$$\max_{x\in (0,N)} f,$$

but for the open interval $(0,N)$, the maximum need not exist, so you should use the closed interval $[0,N]$ there (or write $\sup$).

But then it works.

---

The usual way to prove the boundedness of $f$ would be to choose one particular $\varepsilon > 0$. $\varepsilon = 1$ is a common choice. Then, since

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = l_+,$$

there is an $N\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x\geqslant N \Rightarrow \lvert f(x)-l_+\rvert \leqslant 1$, so $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant \lvert l_+\rvert + 1$ on $[N,+\infty)$. Since

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = l_-$$

(we have no reason to demand $l_+ = l_-$, so let's do it for the more general situation), there is an $M\in \mathbb{R}$ with $x \leqslant M \Rightarrow \lvert f(x)-l_-\rvert \leqslant 1$, so $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant \lvert l_-\rvert+1$ on $(-\infty,M]$.

If $M < N$, let $A = \max\limits_{x\in [M,N]} \lvert f(x)\rvert$, else let $A = 0$. Then we have

$$\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant \max \{ A ,\, \lvert l_-\rvert + 1,\, \lvert l_+\rvert + 1\}.$$

Comment: perfect! Thanks you Daniel ;-)